# Elementor does not detect my images on an html widget. Is there any erro on my code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, elementor

I am doing a Slide, from my website, I currently edit my pages with Elementor, and I added an HTML widget, to put my code and see if it works. Y uploaded some images in my hosting in a specific folder, and if you try the make the reference, it does not work. It doesn't seem to be an error in the reference, but it doesn't show me any picture.

I don't know if I have made an error in my code, or its just that Elementor is crazy. ;)

Here my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {box-sizing: border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif; margin:0}
.mySlides {display: none}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img href="https://www.mediassegur.com/img/simg1.JPG" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img href="https://www.mediassegur.com/img/simg2.JPG" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img href="https://www.mediassegur.com/img/simg3.JPG" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img href="https://www.mediassegur.com/img/simg4.JPG" style="width:100%">
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <img href="https://www.mediassegur.com/img/simg5.JPG" style="width:100%">
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span> 

</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't need the `<!doctype html>` and the `html`, `head`, `body` tags. This seems to be a very messy way of adding a image slider to the page, have you tried using the build in image slider widget of Elementor ? [Elementor Documentation](https://elementor.com/help/image-carousel-widget/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<img href="` it should have been `<img src="`

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0
}

.mySlides {
  display: none
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Next & previous buttons */

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}


/* Position the "next button" to the right */

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev,
  .next,
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/59/-127wiki.jpg/220px--127wiki.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRAiNZzQqw5hwaWyZX3-KPG5gBHcMkjqPB6KtIakiiY56snwjgt" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://www.himgs.com/imagenes/hello/social/hello-fb-logo.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/6b/Hello_Web_Series_%28Wordmark%29_Logo.png" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span>

</div>
```